# Beyblade MF for DS: How do I change Bey equipments before Story Mode battles?

Tags: nintendo-ds, beyblade-metal-fusion

I went to Bey Garage and bought many new improvement items, and customised my Bey from the MOD.

Now, when I save it and go over to Story Mode, and resume my play, I cannot change anything or into another Bey.

I'm attaching a picture. It's of the time when I "Equip" my Beyblade. It's exactly what happens before a battle too. Here, I chose to edit the face type. You can see that there actually **are** two face types. How do I pick the other one? (the one I bought from Bey Garage).
 [image]

In the same Bey Garage, I also edited my Bey and gave it the second face type (a Leone). But those customisations don't come in Story Mode.